# finding modularity and community membership

Tags: r, social-networking, graph-theory, igraph, modularity

I want to find 1) the modularity of a network and find 2) the identities of the nodes in each community.

I think this is the way to get modularity:

```
g <- graph.full(5) %du% graph.full(5) %du% graph.full(5)
g <- add.edges(g, c(1,6, 1,11, 6, 11))
ebc <- edge.betweenness.community(g)

sizes(ebc)
#Community sizes
#1 2 3 
#5 5 5 

modularity(g,membership(ebc))
#[1] 0.5757576
```

but on [this link by Gabor](http://igraph.wikidot.com/community-detection-in-r#toc2) I get this code:

```
memberships <- list()
G <- graph.full(5) %du% graph.full(5) %du% graph.full(5)
G <- add.edges(G, c(1,6, 1,11, 6, 11))

### edge.betweenness.community
ebc <- edge.betweenness.community(G)
mods <- sapply(0:ecount(G), function(i) {
  g2 <- delete.edges(G, ebc$removed.edges[seq(length=i)])
  cl <- clusters(g2)$membership
  modularity(G, cl)
})

g2 <- delete.edges(G, ebc$removed.edges[1:(which.max(mods)-1)])
memberships$`Edge betweenness` <- clusters(g2)$membership
```

This seems to be doing the same thing that I am, I think that the `delete.edges` and `clusters` is about splitting the modules into separate components by deleting the connecting edges and then getting the IDs of nodes in each component.

Although there are a few questions I have:

1. In @Gabor Csardil 's code why does the `modularity` call use `clusters(G)$membership` and not `ebc` like I did in my example? What is the difference? (I would have thought that would overestimate actual modularity?) There also seems to be an alternate using `community.to.membership`
2. The `mods` code returns this error which I do not understand which is partly why I cannot explore `g2` and `cl` to see more of what is happening:

> Error in delete.edges(G, ebc$removed.edges[seq(length = i)]) : 
>     At iterators.c:1809 : Cannot create iterator, invalid edge id, Invalid vertex id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer is that the code in the wiki is outdated. It works with igraph version 0.5.x, but not with 0.6.x. More specifically:

1. In igraph version 0.5.x there was no direct way to get the membership vector, in version 0.6.x you can just say `membership(ebc)`.
2. In version 0.5.x vertex ids start with zero, in version 0.6.x they start with one, so you don't meed to subtract one in the `delete.edges()` line.

Comment: thank you Gabor so `membership(ebc)` does give me what I want. Although the `delete.edges` call inside the `mod` was the one causing therror and I this doesnt have -1 subtraction for zero indexing. i.e `g2 <- delete.edges(G, ebc$removed.edges[seq(length=i)])`

Comment: I see, it is the same error, anyway, because `$removed.edges` is zero-based, I guess. Anyway, it does not really matter, just use `membership()` and `cutat()` if you want to cut the dendrogram somewhere else.

Comment: this [link](http://www.sixhat.net/finding-communities-in-networks-with-r-and-igraph.html) though seems to suggest that `mods` is about getting a range of modularities for each possible split. Don't you need this to work out which possible split has the highest modularity? or does `membership` give you the division with the highest modularity already now?

Comment: nope modularity does give the highest split `?communities` "modularity gives the modularity score of the partitioning. (See modularity.igraph for details. For algorithms that do not result a single partitioning, the highest modularity value is returned."